# Putting Map content into another Map, based on condition

Tags: java, hashmap, maps

I've tried searching for ways of doing this and they don't seem to solve my problem.

I have a Map:

```
Map<String,Element> elements = new HashMap<>();
```

I would like to put it into another Map; given a simple condition:

```
if (key.charAt(0) == 'W') //Does the start of the key have a "W"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to put an entire map into another map if *any* key starts with 'W' or you want to check each Map Entry and if its key starts with 'W' put that entry only into the other map?

Comment: The latter. I want to put any key/value pairs which have a key that starts with 'W'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize Java 8 to perform the following:

```
elements.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.startsWith("W"));
```

It removes every entry whose key does not start with `W`.

If you want to retain the first `Map`, simply create another `Map` first:

```
Map<String, Element> newElements = new HashMap<>(elements);

newElements.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.startsWith("W"));
```

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. This is a very clean and concise answer, as well as being my first introduction (I think) to using Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your use case is. I'm going to assume you're using java 8.

If you want a new map with the filtered entries you could do

```
Map<String,Element> newElements = elements.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("W"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey(), Entry::getValue()));
```

If you already have the other map and you just want to add the entries to it you could use:

```
//assuming Map<String,Element> newElements = some appropriately initialized map
elements.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("W"))
    .forEach(entry -> newElements.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

You could also pass the result of the first option to putAll on the second map if you'd rather. Though in that case I'd be partial to the second option.

Answer (score 1):

This worked just fine for me:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Map<String,String> elements = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,String> elements2 = new HashMap<>();//the second map
        elements.put("A", new String("A"));
        elements.put("B", new String("B"));
        elements.put("W1", new String("W1"));
        elements.put("W2", new String("W2"));


        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : elements.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getKey().charAt(0) == 'W')
                elements2.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : elements2.entrySet())
        {
            //printing the elements of the second map
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());            
        }
    }
}
```

giving the following output:

```
W1/W1
W2/W2
```